# how we can display pound and euro symbol in android TextView?

Tags: android

How do I display pound(£) and euro(€) symbol in `TextView`?

need help!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can copy and paste them. € £

Here is a list of more [unicode characters](https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/%7Etomw/java/unicode.html)

Answer (score 19):

```
String euro = "\u20ac";

String pound = "\u00a3";

tvAmount.setText(euro);

tvCurrency.setText(pound);
```

And also you can check list of other symbol [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf)

Answer (score 13):

More appropriate way will be to do it using `Currency`.

```
String euro = Currency.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).getCurrencyCode();
String pound = Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK).getCurrencyCode();
```

Comment: Wow wow, I didn't know there exists an API like this to fix my headache. +1 for letting me know that.

Comment: Glad to know that it was helpful :)

Comment: That gets you the currency code, not the symbol. The symbol is easily achieved by using the getSymbol() method as in -> Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK).getSymbol()